Exercise on Riemann Sphere
I am trying to do the following exercise on complex numbers and stereographic projection:
"Show that $z$ and $z'$ correspond to diametrically opposite points on the Riemann sphere if and only if $z\bar z'=-1$".
I know that the inverse of the stereographic projection is $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow S^2-\{\infty\}$ defined as: $\varphi(z)=\left(\frac{z+\bar z}{|z|^2+1},-i\frac{z-\bar z}{|z|^2+1},\frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1}\right)$. Assuming $z=a+ib$ and $z'=a'+ib'$, I tried to impose that $\varphi(z')=-\varphi(z)$, thus obtaining a system of three equations:
$a'(a^2+b^2+1)=-a(a'^2+b'^2+1)$
$b'(a^2+b^2+1)=-b(a'^2+b'^2+1)$
$(a'^2+b'^2-1)(a^2+b^2+1)=(a^2+b^2-1)(a'^2+b'^2+1)$
On the other hand, $z\bar z'=-1 \iff aa'+bb'=-1$ and $a'b-ab'=0$. These two equations seems to have nothing in common with the system above....Is there any way to link these conditions?
Thanks for any answer and help!
PS: I have solved the $\Longleftarrow$ implication by direct calculation, but I have several difficulties working out the other implication.
